# How to get current System date in SmartGwt application

Tags: java, javascript, date, smartgwt

How to get current system date in Smartgwt application (Merely javascript). I need date to be printed as 25 October 2010 something like this. Currently i am using 
the following code:

```
String currentDate ;
java.util.Date date = new Date();
String tempDate = date.toString();
String[] currDate = tempDate.split(" ");
currentDate = currDate[2] + " " + currDate[1] + " "
        + currDate[currDate.length - 1];
```

But i guess this will not work if the locale of the system/server changes. Can you suggest me any method to get date ?

Comment: You should be careful with this. What do you want to accomplish with this Date ? You might want to get it from the Server or simply calculate the Date on the Server when the user submits a request. If not you may have wildly different date times based on each of the users clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call Javascript method using JSNI:

```
public native String getLocaleDateString() /*-{
    return new Date().toLocaleDateString();
}-*/;
```

GWT 2.1 will introduce the new [`JsDate`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsDate.html) class:

```
JsDate.create().toLocaleDateString();
```

Answer (score 3):

In SmartGWT, there is a DateUtil class that does exactly what you need; see http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/util/DateUtil.html

You can find an usage example on the SmartGWT forums here: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=13920&highlight=DateUtil

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in smart gwt u can use java classes.

this date will be on client side date .

This will work.....